# Fetch Spring Batch Job Execution with specific Job parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I want to fetch the `lastJobExecution` with specific job parameter.
**Scenario**:
I want to store  `userEmail` as a job parameter, and then fetch last job execution of that user :

```
Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("userEmail", new JobParameter("something@xyz.com", true));
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(parameters);

jobRepository.getLastJobExecution("jobName", jobParameters)
```

**Issue in above approach:**
If I only use put only `userEmail` as a job parameter, same user wont be able to trigger another job once previous job is finished, as error: `A job instance already exists with given job parameters`.

So I am planning to add `userEmail` + `startTime` as job parameter. So same user can trigger multiple jobs.
However, now I want to fetch last job execution of that user, I need both  `userEmail` + `startTime`

```
Map<String, JobParameter> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("userEmail", new JobParameter("something@xyz.com", true));
parameters.put("startTime", new JobParameter(123L, true));
JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParameters(parameters);

jobRepository.getLastJobExecution("jobName", jobParameters)
```

But I dont have `startTime` when fetching last job execution of that user.

Is there any way to fetch last job execution with only 1 job parameter?
Or do I need to write my own JdbcTemplate-based DAO implementation to run the select query ?

Tried using long way, like fetch all job executions by job name and then filter.
But this is quite inefficient way.

Answer (score 1):

Identifying job parameters are hashed together to produce a key that is used to identify job instances. So there is no direct way to fetch the last job execution of a job instance with a single parameter. You need to fetch is yourself with a custom SQL query or programmatically by filtering job executions as you did.

That said, it feels like this a job parameters design issue, rather than a limitation in Spring Batch. The choice of start time a job parameter is not suitable to your case as it is not constant in time, hence you can't have it when fetching the last job execution. You need to find a way to uniquely identify job instances which allows you to have all information needed when fetching executions.